# SignHereTabs is appearing for both the signers in the same document

Tags: docusignapi

I am sending the same envelope/document to two signers where the order ID is different (the notification to sign will go to second signer only if first signer has already signed the document). The problem I am facing here is I have two anchor strings for each signers but **SignHereTabs** are appearing for both signers. Please help me with it.

```
a!toJson(
  {
    "emailSubject": ri!emailSubject,
    "message":ri!emailBody,
    "recipients": {
      "signers": {
        {
          "email":"richard@xyz.com",
          "name": "Richard",
          "recipientId": 1,
          "routingOrder": 1,
          "tabs": {
            "signHereTabs": {
              {
                "anchorString": "First_Sign_Here",
                "anchorUnits": "mms",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "name": "Please sign here",
                "optional": "false",
                "recipientId": 1,
                "scaleValue": 1,
                "tabLabel": "signer1sig"
              }
            },
            "dateSignedTabs": {
              {
                "anchorString": "First_Signed_Date",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "fontSize": "Size12",
                "name": "Date Signed Date",
                "recipientId":  1,
                "tabLabel": "date_signed"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "email":"Dave@xyz.com",
          "name": "Dave",
          "recipientId": 2,
          "routingOrder": 2,
          "tabs": {
            "signHereTabs": {
              {
                "anchorString": "Second_Sign_Here",
                "anchorUnits": "mms",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "name": "Please sign here 2",
                "optional": "false",
                "recipientId": 2,
                "scaleValue": 2,
                "tabLabel": "signer2sig"
              }
            },
            "dateSignedTabs": {
              {
                "anchorString": "Second_Signed_Date",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "fontSize": "Size12",
                "name": "Date Signed Date",
                "recipientId":  2,
                "tabLabel": "date_signed2"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems your json is malformed, trying the code below works for me:

```
{
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "name": "test 1",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "accessCode": "98371",
        "routingOrder": 1,
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "anchorString": "First_Sign_Here",
                "anchorUnits": "mms",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "name": "Please sign here",
                "optional": "false",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "scaleValue": 1,
                "tabLabel": "signer1sig"
            }
          ],
          "dateSignedTabs": [ {
                "anchorString": "First_Signed_Date",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "fontSize": "Size12",
                "name": "Date Signed Date",
                "recipientId":  "1",
                "tabLabel": "date_signed"
                 }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "email": "test1@test.com",
        "name": "Test Test",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "accessCode": "98371",
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
                "anchorString": "Second_Sign_Here",
                "anchorUnits": "mms",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "name": "Please sign here 2",
                "optional": "false",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "scaleValue": 2,
                "tabLabel": "signer2sig"
            }],
            "dateSignedTabs": [ {
                "anchorString": "Second_Signed_Date",
                "anchorYOffset": "0",
                "fontSize": "Size12",
                "name": "Date Signed Date",
                "recipientId":  "2",
                "tabLabel": "date_signed"
                 }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "emailSubject": "This is a test envelope",
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "test.pdf",
      "fileExtension":"pdf",
      "documentBase64": ""
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Comment: I did try the json you have suggested, but the result is same. I see SignHereTabs of both the signers when the notification received for first signer. What I am expecting here is when the first signer receives notification it can only see the SignHereTab for the tag which he is intended to sign but not for the second signer.

Comment: It might be best to open a support case. There, you can provide an envelope ID and an API log showing the full content of the call (https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=jux1643235969954&topicId=poz1578456669909.html&_LANG=enus)